# pythonanywhere - SUPER SLOW?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, pythonanywhere, python-telegram-bot

I've made a telegram bot, that sends a request to a certain API and returns the answer to the bot.
when I run the app locally, it takes like 2-3 seconds to execute a request and send the answer to the user, but when its webhook to pythonanywhere, it takes 5-10 minutes to execute a request.
is it really that slow? or something is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That really seems like something's wrong. Instrument your code with some timing information so you can see where it's spending it's time. Then you can start to try to work out why there's such a big difference.